# notifyDataSetChanged() not working for custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have already went through many similar question but still I am not getting the answer.

I am using custom adapter having arraylist for listview when there is some change on seek bar arraylist is modified and I want to show this changes on listview, I am doig this in following two ways

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_showcontactlist);
    customAdapter = new ContactListViewAdapter(this);
    customAdapter.setList(contactList);
    lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    contactList_temp = new ArrayList<ContactBean>(contactList);
```

attempt 1)

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    for (ContactBean object : contactList_temp) {
        int sal = Integer.parseInt(object.getSalary());
        if (sal > progress) {
            contactList.remove(object);
        }

    }

    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    contactList.clear();
    contactList.addAll(contactList_temp);
}
```

attempt 2)

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    contactList.clear();

    for (ContactBean object : contactList_temp) {
        int sal = Integer.parseInt(object.getSalary());
        if (sal < progress) {
            contactList.add(object);
                        }
    }
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    contactList.addAll(contactList_temp);
}
```

setList method in my adapter class:

```
public void setList(ArrayList<ContactBean> newList) {
    this.m_contactlist = newList;
    }
```

My problem is both methods are logically doing same task but my 1 method is not listview remains same but second method is working properly listview is reflecting changes as expected. So i want to know what is the reason behind this.

Answer (score 3):

*You are calling `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` before changing the data of adapter. You need to call this method after changing the data of adapter.*

*See below for edit*

In attempt 1:-

Code should be

```
// customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // NOT HERE
contactList.clear();
contactList.addAll(contactList_temp);
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // MUST BE HERE
```

In attempt 2

Code should be

```
// customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // NOT HERE
contactList.addAll(contactList_temp);
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // MUST BE HERE
```

Comment: no. I want to show modified contents of contactlist on text view and for further operation I am reassigning contactlist with its backup contactlist_temp, I dont want to show contents of contactlist_temp.

Comment: I don't think that you can modify the list after notifyDataSetChanged which you used for list. I am sure that if you scroll listview, it will give an error. By the way your both code are not logically same, so they are behaving different.

Answer (score 2):

one way to implement changing information mid run in a custom adapter is to add a method for that and in that method (after ensuring you're on the UI thread), notifyDatasetChage.

```
public void setList(List<T> data) {
  this.mData = data;
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         notifyDatasetChanged();
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please notice, if you put this in the adapter, that very likely `notifyDatasetChanged();` will raise an error because it is not referred to the adapter context in that place.